# How to access vb.net button click event on modal popup button click event?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms

my source code in design part is:

```
<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" Style="display: none" CssClass="modalPopup">
        <asp:Panel ID="Panel3" runat="server" Style="cursor: move;background-color:#DDDDDD;border:solid 1px Gray;color:Black">
            <div>
                <p>Would you like to book the seat?</p>
            </div>
        </asp:Panel>
            <div> 
                <p style="text-align: center;">
                    <asp:Button ID="OkButton" runat="server" Text="OK" OnClick="OkButton_Click" />                     
                    <asp:Button ID="CancelButton" runat="server" Text="Cancel" />
                </p>
            </div>                
    </asp:Panel>
```

I want to access OkButton_Click in vb.net
The code is as follows:

```
 Protected Sub OkButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles OkButton.Click
        Dim con As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.Oledb.4.0 ;data source=" & Server.MapPath(".\App_Data\IFFI.mdb") & ";")
        Dim Cmd As OleDbCommand
        Dim Qry As String
        con.Open()
        Qry = "update seat_layout set lock_status=1,booked_status=1 where theatre_id='" + ddl_theatre.SelectedValue.ToString() + "' and seat_id='" + Session("seat_id").ToString() + "'"
        Dim img As Button
        img.BackColor = Drawing.Color.Purple
        img.Enabled = False
        Cmd = New OleDbCommand(Qry, con)
        Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        con.Close()
    End Sub
```

Ok button click is not accessing click event.

Answer (score 3):

Try changing the sub to "public" instead of "protected".
(I apologize if this question was too old for me to answer it now).